# How to avoid capturing stdout when returning a value

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate AWS configuration with Powershell:

```bsh
Function LoginAndGetUser {
    Write-Host "Please enter credentials..."
    & aws configure

    $user = aws iam get-user
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "Error whilst getting user" }
    return $user  | ConvertFrom-Json
}
```

Calling the function and discarding the returned user works:

```bsh
LoginAndGetUser

> Please enter credentials...
> AWS Access Key ID [****************...]: # etc
> User
> ----
> @{Path=/; UserName=foo; UserId=bar; Arn=baz; CreateDate=now}
```

However, if I assign the result to a variable it seems that the variable is "capturing" stdout:

```bsh
$foo = LoginAndGetUser
$foo

> Please enter credentials...
> # "hangs". I can type in my credentials and hit enter, but I dont get the "AWS Access Key ID" prompt
```

How do I make the `LoginAndGetUser` function return a value without capturing the stdout from `& aws configure`?

I've tried `& aws configure | Write-host` but that makes both variants capture...

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `$script:` or `$global:` variable and have you function modify that.  While adjusting variables outside of your Function's scope is not practiced very often, modules are the [one place you will typically see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#modules) them used.

You'd modify your function above to use a `$module` or $script` level variable instead, like this.

```
$script:awsUser = $user | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then the rest of your module or scripts would expect this variable to be specified.  If it is `$null`, it could even throw a controlled error and instruct the user to run `Connect-AwsAccount` first.